# PostgreSql, QSqlDatabase: Failed to open Database

Tags: python, postgresql, pyqt, pyqt5, qsqldatabase

My system: Windows 10 Pro 16299, Qt, PyQt 5.11.2, Python 3.6, PostgreSql 10

I tried to use QTableView/QSqlTableModel for in my gui to work with postgresql data. However, I am not able to open the database. I get the error message “Driver not loaded Driver not loaded”.

A new installation of Qt, PostgreSql and PyQt has not solved the problem. I tried also “Dependency Walker” to look for missing dlls, but was not able use the given information.

Do you have an idea how to fix this problem?

As an alternative: Is it possible to use QTableView/QSqlTableModel with psycopg2 (instead of QSqlDatabase)?

Thank you very much in advance!

---

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel  
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication  
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

  app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
  db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")   
  db.setHostName("localhost")  
  db.setPort(5432)  
  db.setDatabaseName("Test")  
  db.setUserName("postgres")  
  db.setPassword("xxxxx")  
  if (db.open() == False):  
    QMessageBox.critical(None, "Error", db.lastError().text())   
  else:  
    Print("Connected")
```

---

Dependency Walker Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the Postgres driver:

```
C:\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlpsql.dll
```

where `C:\Python\Python36` is your Python installation directory.

Load this file with dependency walker and check whether `libpq.dll` and all its dependencies can be found.

Typically the two Postgres folders have to be set on the system path:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\lib\
```

The dll's version incompatibility (64-bit vs 32-bit) may be one of the probable problems.

Comment: I added ‪C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\ and C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\lib\ to the path variable. Same error. However, the screenshot from "Dependeny Walker" (please see above) shows that something is missing. How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, dependencies looks pretty good. I would say *it must run!* Set the new `PATH` in system properties and restart Windows?

Comment: + cleaned up the user properties. Now it is working!! Thanks a lot!!